# Customizing a combobox in WPF && winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, combobox

In my wpf application I have this issue. The items source of this combobox contains 20000 elements

```
 <ComboBox   Height="30" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTheme}" DisplayMemberPath="theme_libelle" />
```

the problem is when I select it, it takes a lot of time to be opened even the item source is a simple list of string.

I tried to use the virtualization of its panel but I get the same result . when I replaced it by the `WinForms ComboBox` I get a perfect result: it takes a second to be opened.

```
<WindowsFormsHost >
<WinForms:ComboBox DataSource="MyTheme" SelectedIndex="0"></WinForms:ComboBox>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
```

I need to know how can I implement a customized combobox which inherits from `winforms combobox` and implements the required dependency properties and methods to be used in binding as the `WPF ComboBox`

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I replicate your conditions and add 20000 items to a combobox, it takes about 27 seconds to open the combobox.

When using the `VirtualizingStackPanel` as shown below, the combobox opens in less than 1 second.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LotsOfItems}"
          MinWidth="100">
   <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <VirtualizingStackPanel />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28480621/107899), if the virtualizing panel is not working, there is most likely a problem in the environment you are running.

Comment: thanks , I found why it didn't work for me , I used this ressourcedictionnary `pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml"` which makes the virtualization unused, I delete it and it works !!!